# Not changing a page if a user dont have empty cart

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. I have on my eshop a cart. In a cart is basically 0,-. If I add a item to cart, final price will be change by price of product. fFor example 20,-. And i want to do if a user press a button to continue in buying to pay, it will change site in my page. (To page "Eshop-Platba.html"). But I need to do if a user have 0,- in cart, it will alert him that he dont have any product in the cart. Now is alerting everytime, including when the final price is changed by added products. Any solutions?

```
function prejitKPlatbe() {
KosikKontrola = document.getElementsByClassName('kosik-celkem-cena')[0]
var cena = parseFloat(KosikKontrola.innerText.replace(',-', ''))
if (cena = '0') {
    alert('V košíku nemáte žádný produkt.')
    return
}
else {
    window.location.href = 'Eshop-Platba.html'
}   
}
```

Comment: You're equalizing, but not comparing. Switch to this. `if (cena == '0')`